# Is there any way to enable external sharing for the tenant-my.sharepoint.com domain with Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, mysite, external-users

I want to enable external sharing for the tenant-my.sharepoint.com domain so that external users can see people's profile pictures, which are stored at https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx?id=%2FUser%20Photos%2FProfile%20Pictures. Right now, external users only get the default anonymous grey faceless picture when profile pictures show up, and when they try to open the profile picture in a separate tab, it says that external sharing is disabled for the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to SharePoint admin center-> site collections, choose the site collection  https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com and click sharing.

[image]

Comment: How weird, it looked like that setting was already on allow anonymous access links, but it wasn't working until I resaved the settings. Thanks very much!